# MongoDB aggregation query of subdocument in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, mongodb, nosql

I am working on a stats dashboard for a meditations application, and I'm having trouble constructing a MongoDB query to retrieve the most listened meditations based on user progress. The relevant collections are `users` and `meditations`.

A user document in the `users` collection looks like this:

```json
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"627b519f73b2bd3375f5a7a5"
   },
   "userProgress":{
      "meditationsPracticed":[
         {
            "timestamp":"11.5.2022, 9:03:34",
            "id":"5ef2ff0af1a23752be00651f"
         },
         {
            "timestamp":"11.5.2022, 12:46:03",
            "id":"5eca520c10fe0480d350c9a4"
         },
         /* more meditations */
      ]
   }
}
```

And a meditation document in the `meditations` collection looks like this:

```json
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5eca520c10fe0480d350c9ac"
   },
   "name":"Sleep Well",
   "duration":{
      "$numberInt":"250"
   }
}
```

I want to create a query that retrieves the most listened meditations based on the `id` values in the `meditationsPracticed` array within the `userProgress` field of the user document.

Any help with constructing this MongoDB query would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried multiple queries with $unwind and $lookup with no success

Comment: To clarify, you basically want to retrieve the one "meditation" ID which occurs most times in the `meditationsPracticed` array, given an input of a user ID?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but storing date/time values as **string** is design flaw, you should **never** do that. Store always prover `Date` objects.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what "most listened mediations" means?  Is it a simple count of the unique mediation ids in the array across all docs or for *each* doc?  Or a sum of the durations?   If the latter, `duration` seems a candidate to appear in the `meditationsPracticed` array, not a separate table.   Perhaps a sample output document would help as well.

Answer (score 1):

`$unwind` at `meditationsPracticed` level first. Perform `$group` to get the count by `meditations` id. Compute `$rank` with `$setWindowFields` for the case that you have multiple top meditations count. Then, with the top meditation entry, you can `$lookup` to fetch back from `meditations` collection.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "627b519f73b2bd3375f5a7a5"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$userProgress.meditationsPracticed"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$toObjectId": "$userProgress.meditationsPracticed.id"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$_id",
      "sortBy": {
        "count": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "rank": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "meditations",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "meditationsLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$meditationsLookup",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T4uzFwSQjG_)